# Assigning src of img tag dynamically using JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, firebase, image

I have been reading some Data from Firebase and am calling a function. It goes on like

```
function create(link){
    ----
}
```

Now, I have created Image tag inside Body of HTML dynamically inside the above function and assigned it both Class and ID.

Then, I call another function to fetch data from that URL

Back to my function again image should be displayed properly

```
function create(link) {

    let bodyElement = document.body;
    

    let imageElement = document.createElement('img');


    imageElement.className = "image";
    imageElement.id="imgg";
    

    download(link);

    imageElement.setAttribute("alt", "Image from Unsplash");


  }

 
  function download(link) {
    let url= link;
    console.log(url);

    if (!url) return;
 
 
    const req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.responseType = "text/html";
 
    req.onload = function(e) {
      var img = new Image();
      
      document.getElementById("imgg").src = this.response;
    }
 
  }
```

So consider I am calling this entire create() 10 times.

I'll be getting 10 different links from Firebase and each and every time new image tag should be created and appended to Body of HTML

But, I am getting first image succesfully and rest of the images are just blank. src=" " of rest of images is just not even created.

It is being written only for first Function call().

Please guide me through. I couldn't see where I am wrong.

Comment: An `id` is supposed to be unique. `document.getElementById("imgg")` will always refer to the first one it finds, which is the first image you created. There's a bunch of other issues with your code but a quick fix is to simply pass the created `imageElement` to the `download` function as 2nd parameter, that way the onload function can just use that.

Comment: Yeah but I need to create it outside so that I can append it to other div's

Comment: Pass imageElement to download() function and use it to set src.

Answer (score 0):

Found it. It's really simple change in code.

I passed imageelement as argument to download() function and modified code as

```
 
  function download(link,imageElement) {
    let url= link;
    console.log(url);

    if (!url) return;
 
 
    const req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.responseType = "text/html";
 
    req.onload = function(e) {
      var img = new Image();
      
      imageElement.src = this.response;
    }
 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is the scope, you are creating one img element and changing the src on that img, try something like this:

```js
const createLink = (link) => {
    let parentDiv = document.getElementById("imgLinks");
    let count = 0;

    while (count < 10) {
        let imageElement = document.createElement("img");
        imageElement.className = "image";
        imageElement.id = "imgg";
        imageElement.setAttribute("alt", "Image from Unsplash");
        imageElement.setAttribute("src", `${link}${count}?set=set2`);
        parentDiv.append(imageElement);
        count++;
    }
};

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (e) => {
    createLink("https://robohash.org/");
});
```

```html
<div id="imgLinks"></div>
```